# what is the difference getContentMd5() and getETag() of aws s3 PutObjectResult

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

`getEtag()` seems to return base64 encoded md5. So what does `getContentMd5` return? How are they related?

**One example:**

```
 getContentMd5() -> /yoLi66uT7Q6qaverVTqrQ==
 getEtag() -> ff2a0b8baeae4fb43aa9abdead54eaad
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same value -- the md5 hash of the object -- encoded two different ways.

An MD5 hash consists of 16 bytes, but they are not all printable characters.  The ETag is the md5 hash, hex-encoded (**not** base64, as the question suggests) -- hex encoding uses 32 characters to encode 16 bytes.

Meanwhile, Content-MD5 is the md5 hash, base64 encoded, which uses 24 characters to encode 16 bytes.

Comment: I did hex decode for the  getEtag() and base64 decode for getContentMd5() and they end up in the same string. AWS doc should make it clear.

Comment: @WeiZhu - they are different in case of multipart upload.